# Smallest Ordinal which satisfies an equation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

How can I find the smallest ordinal $\beta$ which satisfies the equation:

$\omega + \beta = \beta\;$?

Comment: Try to use this formula as an inductive definition of $\beta$ and see where it goes.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Observe that it also has to satisfy

$$\omega+\omega+\beta=\omega+\beta=\beta\;,$$

$$\omega+\omega+\omega+\beta=\omega+\beta=\beta\;,$$

and in general $\omega\cdot n+\beta=\beta$ for $n\in\omega$. That fact should tell you what $\beta$ has to look like.

Comment: $\beta = \omega \cdot \omega$?

Comment: @GoodWilly: That’s right; the equations in the hint tell you that nothing smaller will work, and it’s easy to check that $\omega\cdot\omega$ does work.